# show that the abc conjecture implies that there are at most finitely many solutions to the following diophantine equation:

Tags: number-theory

Show that the abc conjecture implies that there are at most finitely many solutions to the following diophantine equation:

$x^5-y^2z^3 = 1$ , where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $yz \neq 0$.

I tried using the following conjecture in my book:

$\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have for all but finitely many $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ with $a+b+c = 0$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ that:

$\max\{\log|a|,\log|b|,\log|c|\} < (1+\epsilon) \log(|rad(abc)|)$.

with this information we see:

$\max\{5\log|x|,3\log|z|+2\log|y|,0\} < (1 + \epsilon) \log(|rad(-x^5y^2z^3)| = (1 + \epsilon) \log(|rad(xyz)|$.

Where the last equation follows form the fact that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$

I think i am supposed to get a contradiction at the equation so that we get with the contra-positive all but infinitly many $(a,b,c)$, but i don't see how to do this...

Maybe i am using the wrong theorem here, so hints in the right direction would be much appreciated as well :)

Kees

Comment: $x^5-y^2z^3=1$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ and $xy\not=0$ has **infinitely** many solutions : $(x,y,z)=(1,t,0)$ where $t\not =0\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: How did you come up with your answer if i may ask?

Did you use the conjecture i suggested or is there another way of solving this question?

Kees

Comment: Not an answer, I just wrote what I found. Although I know that you want to show that the conjecture implies that there are at most finitely many solutions to the equation, the equation does have infinitely many solutions. What do you think about this fact? (what I implied was that you might have a typo, for example, $xyz\not=0$, instead of $xy\not=0$...)

Comment: very sharp, it's supposed to be $yz \neq 0$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $|x|>1$ (other cases are easy to check). First, assume $|z|=1$. Then $x^5-y^2=1$. Clearly $|y|>1$. Setting $a=1,b=y^2,c=-x^5$ we get $rad(abc)=rad(x^5y^2)=rad(xy)\leq |xy|$ and we have $|x^5|=|y^2+1|\geq|y^2|$ so $|y|\leq |x|^{5/2},rab(abc)\leq |xy|\leq x^{7/2}=|c|^{7/10}$ so $rad(abc)^{10/7}\leq |c|$ and abc conjecture can be applied.

Setting $a=1,b=y^2z^3,c=-x^5$ We have $rad(abc)=rad(x^5y^2z^3)=rad(xyz)\leq |xyz|$. Now $x^5=1+y^2z^3$, so, taking absolute values, $|x|^5=|1+y^2z^3|\geq|y^2z^3|-1\geq |y^2z^2|=|yz|^2$ (the first inequality follows from triangle inequality, and the second one uses $|z|>1$) so $|yz|\leq |x|^{5/2}$ and we can bound $rad(abc)$ like above and apply abc again.

Comment: at the step $|1+y^2z^3| \geq |y^2z^3| -1$, i assume u use a triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. And the inequality right after that is true for $|z|>1$.

Comment: Hmm, the latter fact leaves open the case $|z|=1$, so I will fill that bit in.

Comment: the usage of the triangle inequality is so smart thank you for this insight :)

Comment: one last qestion:

the abc conjecture states that $rad(a,b,c)^{1+\epsilon} < c$, don't we get problems by the fact that we have an '$\leq$' sign instead of '<'

Comment: @KeesTil This doesn't make a significant difference. You can see that because if $rad(abc)^{1+\epsilon}\leq c$, then $rad(abc)^{1+\epsilon/2}<c$, provided $rad(abc)>1$.